# LINE Verify your identity: "An error has occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: google-chrome, android

*Context: [LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(application)) is a program that runs on Windows, Android, iOS. It has no web interface.*

When connecting to LINE on a desktop computer, this "Verify your identity" screen comes up often, and it fails most of the time saying `An error has occurred. Please try again later.`

[image: LINE Verify your identity: An error has occurred. Please try again later.]

What is the most efficient to do in such cases, in order to get connected as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Close the computer app (if running as a Chrome add-on, no need to close Chrome)
2. Kill the Android app
3. Open the computer app again and re-enter your password, it will show a different verification number
4. Open the Android app again
5. You are presented with another number form, fill it with the new verification number
6. It should work this time, even though virtually no time has passed

Comment: This tutorial suggests another solution which involves modifying the app's SQLite data: https://duniati.com/fix-line-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later/